# iPhone: Convert Unicode to string

Tags: unicode-string

I need to convert the following to string and display

```
Overall, the \u2018\u2018typical\u2019\u2019 xyz is broadly expressed
```

I have tried all sort of uncode conversion

```
NSData *asciiData = [desc dataUsingEncoding:NSASCIIStringEncoding   allowLossyConversion:YES]; 
NSString *encodedString = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:asciiData encoding:NSASCIIStringEncoding
```

and:

```
[NSString stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@"\u2018" withString:@""]
```

without success.

Kindly suggest me a solution to this.

Answer (score 1):

```
char cString[] = "\u2018\u2018typical\u2019\u2019";
NSString *string = [NSString stringWithCString:cString encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
NSLog(@"string: %@", string);
```

NSLog output: string: ‘‘typical’’

or

```
NSData *data = [NSData dataWithBytes:cString length:strlen(cString)];
NSString *string = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:data encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
NSLog(@"string: %@", string);
```

NSLog output: string: ‘‘typical’’